# Выравнивание памяти в Delphi

Tags: delphi, память, delphi-xe

1. Когда это желательно/необходимо?
2. Стоит ли об этом вообще задумываться или компилятор сам определит наиболее подходящую модель?
3. Например если программа в основном оперирует байтовыми переменными, байтовыми массивами, есть ли смысл сделать выравнивание памяти по байту? Даст ли это прирост скорости при обращении к памяти/переменным или наоборот будет тормозить современные процессоры?
4. Или если программа заточена под SSE нужно ли компилятору дать команду как-то специально выравнивать для этого память?
5. Есть так же разница выравнивания кода **`{$CODEALIGN n}`** и выравнивания данных **`{$ALIGN n}`** В каких случаях выравнивание кода даёт какой-либо ощутимый результат?

Answer (score 4):

1. Когда профилирование показало, что это необходимо. Или креш.
2. Скорее всего компилятор сам все хорошо сделает. Он умный.
3. Если делать выравнивание по байту, то данные могут находиться не по выровненным адресам. В этом случае загрузка-выгрузка данных "может быть" немного медленнее. Плюс от выравнивания только в том, что можно иногда сэкономить немного памяти или разместить данные правильным образом (например, если парсим сложный бинарный протокол). Но иногда структуры нужно правильно упаковать, что бы они занимали меньше памяти.
4. Если используется SSE, то нужно смотреть в документацию на конкретные команды. Некоторые команды требуют правильно выравнивания и могут не работать, если данные не выровнены или работать сильно медленнее (обычно в два раза). Но обычно компилятор и сам прекрасно управиться. Если же очень сильно хочется помочь компилятору - поставьте выравнивание на 16 или 32.
5. Выравнивание кода нужно, если к примеру, у Вас несколько очень маленьких функций, (десятки байт) и к ним очень часто обращаются. Так как загрузка кода в принципе ничем не отличается от загрузки данных, то, теоретически, можно получить выигрыш. Выравнивание кода ещё бывает нужно на микроконтроллерах, где нужно иногда размещать код правильно в памяти.

Подсуммируем. Если приложение падает, то возможно нужно посмотреть на выравнивание данных, которые передаются в sse инструкции. Если приложение медленно работает, то профилируем, потом выравнием данные, которые используются "тяжелыми функциями" и снова профилируем (и скорее всего ничего не изменится).

Comment: А конкретные примеры может кто-нибудь привести, когда мы увидим реальную разницу в скорости работы при различном выравнивании? Пусть даже это глупые и надуманные примеры. "и скорее всего ничего не изменится" улыбнуло :))

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/262933/

Comment: И самое непонятное: я знаю, что логика моей программы не вылезает за пределы байта, потому использую везде тип байт. Это вроде бы логично, должно быть быстрее и экономить память. Профессор говорит никогда не используйте байт, т.к. обращение к нему будет медленнее, т.к. память по умолчанию выровнена не по байту! Так она выровнена по 8 или 16 байт, тут ни word ни int не поможет. Зачем же тогда использовать бОльшую размерность типов, когда она в принципе не используется?

Comment: Если Вам просто нужна одна переменная типа байт, то можно использвоать и integer (который 4 байта). В некоторых случаях это даже будет быстрее (процессору в большинстве случаев загрузить один байт с памяти или 4 - все равно). Другое дело, если у Вас массив на миллионы элементов. Здесь байт/integer может быть существенным.

Comment: т.е. если у меня 100 байтовых переменных, то по сути они всё равно по-умолчанию выровнены по 8 байтовой границе и обращение к ним должно быть таким же, как и к словам и к integer(т.к. они тоже 8 байт не превышают) и занимают они в памяти 100 x 8 байт (так же как и слова и integer выровненные по той же 8 байтовой границе)? Или выравневается таки не каждая переменная, а начало области данных?

Comment: если я правильно помню, то выровнены по умолчанию они все таки по границе в 4 байта, но это для 32битных систем. Каждая переменная выравнивается отдельно. Но только не думайте, что есть одна одна "область данных". Переменные функции/процедуры выделятся на стеке и живут пока эта функция работает.
Да, выравнивание может быть важно, если переменная локальная и функция рекурсивная. Если рекурсия глубокая, то стек можно быстро исчерпать.

Comment: 8 же? может конечно от версии зависит: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Align_fields_(Delphi)

Comment: Значит теперь 8. Последняя делфи, с которой я работал - это 2007:)

Answer (score 3):

Выравнивание критично, если идёт обращение к данным чужой dll, а параметры передаются в виде record . Если Вы передадите туда запись, которая выровнена не так как в библиотеке, то будет не соответствие параметров (который приведет к сбою!).

Второй вариант это чтение данных при помощи записей.
Есть заголовок файла,например jpeg, Вы сделали запись, которая содержит информацию о заголовке и читается заголовок целиком сразу в вашу структуру. 
Если не написать packed record, то данные в записи будут неправильные.

То есть чаще всего выравнивание нужно при использовании записей.

В остальных прирост производительности может быть и будет при выравнивании, но чаще всего он мало ощутим. Если есть критически важные места, то при проведении оптимизации нужно сделать выравнивание. Но это всего лишь одна из 10-ка процедур оптимизации..